# Close database connection after launch second form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, connection-string

in my application i have two forms.one for login another for actual application. but after successful login database connection made by login form does not terminate. only way to close this connection is close both forms. but i want to close database connection made by login form as soon as successful login. here's my code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {


            string mysqlconnection = string.Format("datasource='{0}';username=uwcentrallogin;port=3306;password=**************;Connect Timeout=20000;Command Timeout=28800", serverip.Text);
            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(mysqlconnection);
            MySqlCommand Selectcommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from wartif.userdata where username='" + this.adminusername.Text.Trim() + "'and adminpassword= '" + this.passwordtext.Text.Trim() + "' ; ", myconn);

            MySqlDataReader myreader;
            myconn.Open();
            myreader = Selectcommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;

            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;

            }

            if (count == 1)
            {



                this.Hide();
                adminview f2 = new adminview(serverip.Text, adminusername.Text, portnumberbox.Text, defdatabase.Text);
                f2.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
                myconn.Close();

            }

            else if (count > 1)
            {


                label4.Text = "duplicatie users exsist ";
            }

            else

            label4.Text = "Not a privileged user";
            label4.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
            errpan.BackColor = Color.Orange;


            myconn.Close();

        }

        catch 
        {


            label4.Text = "mysql database connection is not avialable";
        }



    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        appconfigsave();

        label4.Text = "Your changes has been saved";
        label4.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        errpan.BackColor = Color.Orange;

    }
```

Comment: Not an anser to your question at all but: Really name your labels and buttons, if your application gets bigger you will lose all control of what number was what button / label. Also it will make your code more clear.

Comment: Use parameters in your SQL command to prevent from SQL injections.

Comment: @Sybren thanks for the advice i changed it to parameterized sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
 myconn.Dispose();
```

below your line:

```
myconn.Close();
```

I would also advise you look at `Using` Statments

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

**Example**

```
        if (count == 1)
        {
            this.Hide();
            adminview f2 = new adminview(serverip.Text, adminusername.Text, portnumberbox.Text, defdatabase.Text);
            myconn.Close();
            myconn.Dispose();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I would say that you need to move the line `myconn.Close();` above `f2.ShowDialog();` and add my `Dispose()` line below your `Close()` The reason I say this is because if your dialog `f2` tries to use the SQLConnection while initialising it is not going to be able to because you haven't closed / disposed of your connection yet. See my example in the edit